# Hide css grid item without display none

Tags: html, css, css-grid

I have a css grid. Items are animated in using transform scaleY. I also have a search field which hides items on demand. The problem is when I hide an item (remove shown class) grid is not re-adjusted because it seems like item although it has height 0 / scaleY 0, it still behaves as part of the grid. I have made a demo to illustrate (one item is hidden for display purpose). Can this be achieved without using display none when I hide the items in grid?

```js
var items = document.querySelectorAll('.item:not(.hidden)')

for (var i = 0, len = items.length; i < len; i++) {
  items[i].classList.add('shown')
}
```

```css
.wrap {
  display: grid;
  grid-gap: 1rem;
  justify-items: center;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fill, minmax(300px, 1fr));
}

.item {
  padding: 50px;
  background-color: #ccc;
  overflow: hidden;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  transform: scaleY(0);
  transform-style: flat;
  height: 0;
}

.shown {
  transform: scaleY(1);
  opacity: 1;
  height: auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrap">
  <div class="item">1</div>
  <div class="item hidden">2</div>
  <div class="item">3</div>
  <div class="item">4</div>
  <div class="item">5</div>
  <div class="item">6</div>
  <div class="item">7</div>


</div>
```

Comment: Where is hidden class?

Comment: If you want to hide with js it is always better to hide with CSS and only show with js. In your case I would also look at jquery that makes it so easy

Comment: `.hidden { display: none; }` seems to be visually effective for me. What do you mean with "it still behaves as part of the grid"?

Comment: I dont want to use display none.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want to use display:none you can remove the item.  Why can't you use display:none as that would make it easier to display it later?

```js
var items = document.querySelectorAll('.item:not(.hidden)')

document.querySelectorAll('.hidden')[0].remove()



for (var i = 0, len = items.length; i < len; i++) {
  items[i].classList.add('shown')
}
```

```css
.wrap {
  display: grid;
  grid-gap: 1rem;
  justify-items: center;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fill, minmax(300px, 1fr));
}

.item {
  padding: 50px;
  background-color: #ccc;
  overflow: hidden;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  transform: scaleY(0);
  transform-style: flat;
  height: 0;
}

.shown {
  transform: scaleY(1);
  opacity: 1;
  height: auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrap">
  <div class="item">1</div>
  <div class="item hidden">2</div>
  <div class="item">3</div>
  <div class="item">4</div>
  <div class="item">5</div>
  <div class="item">6</div>
  <div class="item">7</div>


</div>
```

Comment: I show items by adding shown class, hide item by removing shown class. I dont want to use use display none because I cant run my animation in shown class. When I show it with display block afterwards, transition will not run, item will just show immediately, which is not pretty.

Comment: have you looked at grid to try to set the height and width of the item to 0?  Is that possible?

Comment: If I set both width and height to zero I can see the grid still doesnt readjust and it still keeps space for this item.

Comment: just for kicks set the grid display to block after you set the height and width to 0 of the element you want to remove and then immediately set it back to grid.  When it  redisplays, does it work?

Comment: I have managed to solve this by adding position:absolute, visibility:hidden to item.

Comment: that's very clever!